# No sale codigo Qr

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este codigo que estoy tratando de imprelemtar pero lo unico que me imprime es el texto de alt="Código QR, anterior mente me salia un error QRious is not defined que solucione agregando el script de qrious, en este momento no me da error pero tampoco imprime la imagen de Qr

@{Codigo}

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/qrious@4.0.2/dist/qrious.js"></script>
    
    <div class="box">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Formulario" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div style="width:100%;">
    <div> <img alt="Código QR" id="codigo">  </div>
    <script>
    var QR = new QRious({
    element: document.getElementById("#codigo"),
    value: "https://www.youtube.com/",
    size: 300,
    backgroundAlpha: 0,
    foreground: 'blue',
    level: "H",
    });
    </script>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: por qué las etiquetas de c# y asp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores:

- Debes usar un elemento `<canvas>`
- El valor de `id` pasado a `getElemwntById` no debe tener el símbolo `#`.

El código resultante es:

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/qrious@4.0.2/dist/qrious.js"></script>
    
    <div class="box">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="Formulario" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div style="width:100%;">
    <div> <canvas alt="Código QR" id="codigo"></canvas>  </div>
    <script>
    var QR = new QRious({
    element: document.getElementById("codigo"),
    value: "https://www.youtube.com/",
    size: 300,
    backgroundAlpha: 0,
    foreground: 'blue',
    level: "H",
    });
    </script>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: La respuesta me soluciona el problema gracias, pero si no es mucho pedir por que se usa canvas aqui, lo de img lo tome de una pagina web y de otros ejemplos más pero en mi caso no me dio resultado y con canvas si funciono.

Comment: "por que se usa canvas aqui", de acuerdo a la información presentada en los [ejemplos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrious#examples), se tiene que usar un canvas para poder renderizar el código.

Comment: Tal como re comentan, la [documentación](https://github.com/neocotic/qrious) especifica lo siguiente: *QRious is a pure JavaScript library for generating QR codes using HTML5 __canvas__*. Por lo tanto, debes usar un elemento `<canvas>` para poder mostrar el código QR generado. Si la respuesta es válida, la puedes marcar como tal haciendo clic en el checkmark ✅️